# Static variable usage while using Fork-Join

Tags: java, fork-join

Problem statement:-  //This is a example, Actual  array size is very large

suppose there is class A

```
public class A{
    public static int aa[]=new int[5];
    public computeaa(){
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
          aa[i] = useaa(i);
    }
     //this below function can compute aa[i] value
    public int useaa(int i){
           if(i<=0)
                return 1;
           if(aa[i]!=0)
               return aa[i];
           else 
              return useaa[i-1]+useaa[i-2];
    }
}
```

And RecursiveAction class B

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A z=new A();
    A.computeaa();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<B> tasks =new ArrayList<B>();
   for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
      //There is 2 fork will created 
        B =new B();
        tasks.add(B);
        B.fork();
    }
    if (tasks.size() > 0) {
        for (B task : tasks) {
            task.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Doubt?

1. suppose fork 1 computes static variable aa[2], and suppose when fork 2 going to computes aa[2], can this fork 2 get the value aa[2] which was computed by fork1 or it will compute seperately??
2. By my understanding fork 2 in some cases easily access fork1's aa, suppose fork 2 wanted to compute aa[3],It can get the value which was already computed by fork 1. But the problem is suppose when fork 1 will try to compute aa[4], for calculating aa[4], it need aa[3], which fork 1 already computed but can it possible if fork 1 try to get aa[3], but by chance it get the access of aa[3] of fork 1 which was not calculate... again it creating a mess.

I am very puzzle by fork join kindly help

There is simple problem, i want to compute some array which is used by same class, but while creating more then one object i want to use the same array which was computed by other object so that my computation time reduced.
How can i copy or get that array to another object, so that this object doesn't need to compute?

Comment: What about using [`AtomicIntegerArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)?

Comment: Just a hint: when you spend time creating a [mcve] for us: go for proper meaningful names that follow Java naming convention. Anything else dramatically reduces the value of the source code you are putting together for us. Meaning - alone the usage of a and aa and useaa renders your code almost incomprehensible.

Comment: Beyond that: did nobody tell you yet that using static is very often bad practice in oop?

Comment: @AndyTurner i have two dimensional object array, i just used this array as an example

Comment: @GhostCat, i didn't aware about that, do you have any idea then how can i get that computed array from object 1 to object in parallel processing.

Comment: By stepping back and studying good examples for fork/join. Can't say much more... Time to shut down  and go bed over here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. suppose fork 1 computes static variable aa[2], and suppose when fork 2 going to computes aa[2], can this fork 2 get the value aa[2]
>      which was computed by fork1 or it will compute seperately?

Supposing that the two `B` tasks run in different threads -- over which you elect not to exercise any control -- those two threads are accessing the same element of the same array object without any synchronization.  Either thread can read the value written by the other.  Moreover, they may read a different value if they access that array element again.  The program is not correctly synchronized and therefore there is no guarantee of sequential consistency.

> 2. By my understanding fork 2 in some cases easily access fork1's aa, suppose fork 2 wanted to compute aa[3],It can get the value which
>      was already computed by fork 1. But the problem is suppose when fork 1
>      will try to compute aa[4], for calculating aa[4], it need aa[3], which
>      fork 1 already computed but can it possible if fork 1 try to get
>      aa[3], but by chance it get the access of aa[3] of fork 1 which was
>      not calculate... again it creating a mess.

Yes, you judge rightly -- both about possible behaviors and about it being a mess.

> There is simple problem, i want to compute some array which is used by
>   same class, but while creating more then one object i want to use the
>   same array which was computed by other object so that my computation
>   time reduced. How can i copy or get that array to another object, so
>   that this object doesn't need to compute?

Under some circumstances, you might have different threads compute disjoint sections of the array in parallel.  The computation presented in the question is not amenable to that, however, because of the dependencies between the data.  Because no element past index 1 can be computed before the previous 2 have been computed, computation of the elements needs to be serialized, one way or another.  You cannot achieve that any faster than by devoting a single thread to the job.

After such a computation is completed, you can share the initialized array among threads, provided that they synchronize with the completion of the computation one way or another.  Additional synchronization requirements apply if any of the threads *modify* the array after the initial computation is complete.

Your particular case is a bit tricky, because few actions with synchronization significance are present.  In particular, your array elements are not (and cannot be) `final`, and you cannot be confident that the threads in which your tasks run are started only when you `fork()`; if you had the latter then everything the main thread did before would automatically synchronize with the work of the tasks.  As it is, you might do something like this:

```
public class A {
    // not static:
    public int aa[] = new int[5];

    public void computeAa() {
        aa[0] = 1;
        aa[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < aa.length; i++) {
            aa[i] = aa[i - 1] + aa[i - 2];
        }
    }

    public int getAa(int i) {
        return (i < 0) ? 1 : aa[i];
    }
}

public class B extends RecursiveAction {

    private A myA;

    public RecursiveAction(A a) {
        myA = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        synchronized (myA) {
            // ensure that myA's initialization is complete
            while (myA.aa[0] == 0) {
                // not yet initialized
                myA.wait();
            }
        }
        // ... do something with myA (without modifying it) ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A theA = new A();

       synchronized(theA) {
           // synchronize the initialization of theA, because other threads will
           // check it
           theA.computeAa();

           // wake up any threads waiting on the initialization
           theA.notifyAll();
       }

       List<B> tasks = new ArrayList<B>();

       for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
          //There is 2 fork will created 
            B = new B(theA);
            tasks.add(B);
            B.fork();
        }

        for (B task : tasks) {
            task.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Note here that the main thread creates an instance of `A` and initializes it before forking any tasks.  It provides that instance to each `B` (thus they share it).

Comment: Is there is need to synchronized in main method while computeAa, because other thread will only  come to play when program counter in the for loop?

Comment: And the answer seems me perfect, can you clear my above doubt.

Comment: @MukeshGupta, considering only the available API docs for the classes involved gives no basis for supposing that either of the `synchronized` blocks, the `wait()`, or the `notifyAll()` could safely be omitted.  In particular, the relative timing of the `fork()` invocations in the main thread is not sufficient, because different threads can see inter-thread actions such as modifications to shared variables in different orders.  The two synchronized blocks together, along with the particular use of `wait()` and `notifyAll()` ensure an appropriate global order of interthread operations.